# How to do a calendar appoinment scheduler on website?

Tags: php, calendar

What is the best way to have a calendar on my website for client scheduling.  Do i basically hard code a php app or is there something better that i can do? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the calendar in PHP you can try a pre-built solution like [PHP-Calendar](http://www.php-calendar.com/).  If you want to move some of that out into the browser with something like jQuery on the front-end there are other options like the datepicker from [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: Is there an alternative? I am not very acquainted with php calendaring.  I am a new programmer.  I guess i can just use PHP forms and drop downs to do appoinments...